# Rooms not at 69 F set temp

Tags: heat

It is 5 F outside; however, I have not had any problem with getting desired heat in rooms, until today.
We have gas heat in our house.
I hear water thru the hot water baseboard heaters in every room. Rooms are not making it to the set temp of 69 F

Comment: we need a better description of the system; your location, system pressure,, type of baseboard units, Any zoning, etc.

Comment: Have not had problems over what period? Are you new to the home?

Comment: How long has it ben this cold, and how has it worked the rest of this period?

Comment: Where are you located, city/state

Comment: Unless you live in a normally frigid area, your heating system is probably not sized for that big of a temperature difference.  It's a design and cost trade-off; the systems typically aren't oversized  to handle the most extreme possible temperature.  I live in Virginia and single-digit temperatures are pretty unusual.  My system was sized to handle roughly a 60 degree difference.  On those occasions when it's colder by more than that, the furnace can't make up the entire difference.

Comment: "hear" water? Usually the flow is pretty silent, though you might hear the pipes expanding. If you hear the flow, it could be that there is air trapped in the loop. There should be an air scoop to remove the air, and usually an automatic valve to allow more water in. But other comments are right: need more details.

Comment: @fixer1234 -- Some jurisdictions use the building permit process to prohibit sizing the heating system for that big of a temperature difference.

Comment: @fixer1234 -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

As [fixer1234](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/28390) suggests, your heating system is probably not designed to heat your house to 64 Fahrenheit degrees above the outdoor air temperature.

You can provide more heat by running incandescent lights in most rooms of your house. You can also find reasons to cook things that do not require running your kitchen exhaust fan more than usual.

To prevent this problem from happening in the future, you can improve the insulation of your house (such as by adding [storm windows](http://windowefficiencyworks.com/home/products/window_insert/)).  If there are any drafty parts of your house, you can seal cracks to minimize the drafts.

For example, Seattle's Energy Code mandates that builders design heating systems that can heat a house by 46 F° above the outside air temperature.  A typical house built to the 2006 Seattle Energy Code loses its heat as follows:

- 40% to intended draftiness ("Infiltration" or "Air Changes per Hour")
- 20% via the roof, basement floor, and basement walls
- 20% via doors and windows
- 20% via the remaining above-ground walls

Comment: Interesting, and news to me. We routinely need to heat 90-100 Fahrenheit degrees from outdoor here in Minnesota.